# Python Pytest is it possbile to access variables from fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

in my conftest.py i have

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def specific_test_setup(request):
    my_var = "hello world"
```

I want a specific test to use this as a setup. And, be able to use the variables defined in that fixture. For example this is how I would like it too look:

```
class TestHelloWorld:

    def test_hello_world(self, specific_test_setup):
        print(self.my_var)
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to return your variable in fixture :

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def specific_test_setup(request):
    my_var = "hello world"
    return my_var
```

And then use it in your test:

```py
def test_hello_world(self, specific_test_setup):
        print(specific_test_setup)
```

The other way is to use pytest global variable (not sure if it's not deprecated):

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def specific_test_setup(request):
    pytest.my_var = "hello world"

def test_hello_world(self, specific_test_setup):
        print(pytest.my_var)
```

Comment: Would it be a better solution to create a separate class for each test that needs a specific setup? and then set the fixture to class scope?